# Javascript: onLoad function unintentionally activates my EventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why, but my onLoad function activates all of my functions without the buttons actually being clicked. Thanks in advance. I seem to also have trouble putting javascript in backticks. So the javascript is in a JsFiddle

HTML:

```
<title>Jake's Game</title>
<link rel="icon" href="iconname.gif" type="image/gif">
<body>
<div class="WhiteBackground">
    <div id="Input" class="center">
        <p>Player 1</p>
        <input type="text" id="Name1">
        <br>
        <p>Player 2</p>
        <input type="text" id="Name2">
        <br>
        <p>Player 3</p>
        <input type="text" id="Name3">
        <br>
        <p>Player 4</p>
        <input type="text" id="Name4">
        <br>
        <button id="StartGame">Start Game</button>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <p id="Turn"></p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th id="Player1">Player 1</th>
                <th id="Player2">Player 2</th>
                <th id="Player3">Player 3</th>
                <th id="Player4">Player 4</th>
                <th>Shop</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gold</td>
                <td id="Gold1"></td>
                <td id="Gold2"></td>
                <td id="Gold3"></td>
                <td id="Gold4"></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="NoBuy">N/A</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Miners</td>
                <td id="Miners1"></td>
                <td id="Miners2"></td>
                <td id="Miners3"></td>
                <td id="Miners4"></td>
                <td>10000 Gold</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wood</td>
                <td id="Wood1"></td>
                <td id="Wood2"></td>
                <td id="Wood3"></td>
                <td id="Wood4"></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="NoBuy">N/A</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Loggers</td>
                <td id="Loggers1"></td>
                <td id="Loggers2"></td>
                <td id="Loggers3"></td>
                <td id="Loggers4"></td>
                <td>10000 Gold</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button id="EndTurn">End Turn</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/steventang166/gtb74bpr/41/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mate, when you binding event, there is a mistake , do this :

```
 document.getElementById("StartGame").addEventListener("click", StartGame);
document.getElementById("NoBuy").addEventListener("click", NoBuy);
document.getElementById("EndTurn").addEventListener("click", EndTurn);
```

when you do '()' in javascript, it means excute this function right NOW, which can be handy in some cases like self initializing object:

```
(function(){/* do something */})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works can't believe I made such a simple mistake.

Comment: @StevenTang: thanks mate, please tick my answer as right answer ! :)

Comment: In 7 Minutes and I will.